# Twitter.com redirects to search page instead of timeline

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, twitter

Every time I try to access twitter.com, I am being redirected to Twitter's [search results](https://twitter.com/search?q=%7BsearchTerms%7D) page instead of my timeline. If I am already in the timeline and refresh the page, it works fine though. So, I suspected it could be due to any of the extensions I have installed and tried to disable them and try it, that didn't make any difference. Also, other browsers (I tried Firefox and Opera) from the same PC works fine with twitter.com

Is it something to do with Chrome's Omni box, is mine an isolated case or it behaves the same way for other chrome users as well? Though this hasn't impacted me any way, I am just curious to find out what is actually happening here.

If it would help, below are the extensions I currently have installed:

- FasterFox for Chrome
- Adblock
- PushBullet

Google Chrome version: 36.0.1985.143

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search redirects in Chrome more often than not mean that there's a custom Search URL defined under Search settings.

You can check this from Chrome Menu → Settings → Manage Search Engines (or by pasting `chrome://settings/searchEngines` in the omnibar. If there's one defined for twitter, delete that entry and it should work fine after that.